# Transform an entire column using "date" command

Tags: linux, bash, date, awk, sed

Here is a dummy CSV file with 3 rows. The actual file has 7 million rows.

`testdates.csv`:

```
y_m_d
1997-01-01
1985-06-09
1943-07-14
```

The `date` tool can usually be formatted as such , to get the 'day' :

```
date -d "25 JUN 2011" +%A
```

=> output: `Saturday`

Query:  How to provide an entire column as input for the `date +%A` transformation?

The resulting output should be appended to the end of the input file.

Intended output:

```
y_m_d, Day
1997-01-01, Thursday
1985-06-09, Sunday
1943-07-14, Tuesday
```

Answer (score 6):

To read multiples dates from a file using GNU date, you can use the `-f`/`--file` option:

```
$ date -f testdates.csv '+%F, %A'
1997-01-01, Wednesday
1985-06-09, Sunday
1943-07-14, Wednesday
```

Since your file has a header row, we have to skip that, for example using process substitution and sed:

```
date -f <(sed '1d' testdates.csv) '+%F, %A'
```

To get your desired output, combine like this:

```sh
echo 'y_m_d, Day'
date -f <(sed '1d' testdates.csv) '+%F, %A'
```

or write to a new file:

```sh
{
    echo 'y_m_d, Day'
    date -f <(sed '1d' testdates.csv) '+%F, %A'
} > testdates.csv.tmp
```

and after inspection, you can rename with

```
mv testdates.csv.tmp testdates.csv
```

Comment: That `-f` switch sure shows up in a lot of utilities. I had no idea date had it too

Comment: `tail +1 testdates.csv` is more efficient than `sed '1d' testdates.csv`, especially with large files.

Comment: @LéaGris `-n +1`, I assume? It is indeed faster by a factor of about 3 – but for an input file with 7.5M lines, it's about 0.5 s vs. 1.5 s, which seems bearable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to beat [that `date` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825150/7552).

GNU awk would be OK too:

```
gawk -v OFS=', ' '
    NR == 1 {$2 = "Day"}
    NR >  1 {$2 = strftime("%A", mktime(gensub(/-/, " ", "g", $1) " 0 0 0"))}
    1
' testdates.csv
```

```
y_m_d, Day
1997-01-01, Wednesday
1985-06-09, Sunday
1943-07-14, Wednesday
```

Or perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
    print "$_, ", $. == 1
                    ? "Day"
                    : Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y-%m-%d")->strftime("%A")
' testdates.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#/bin/bash

while read datespec; do
  echo $datespec, $(date -d "$datespec" +%A)
done < testdates.csv
```

Output:

```
1997-01-01, Wednesday
1985-06-09, Sunday
1943-07-14, Wednesday
```

Comment: Good job on the conciseness. But, how can I run this Bash script on the input_file `testdates.csv`? Do I pass the input_file as a command line argument?

Comment: @sandra16 it's there on line 5: `done < testdates.csv`

Comment: I see. I wasn't familar with `read-while` loops in Bash.

I get an error: 
`date: invalid date ‘y_m_d’ `                                                                                                                                     ```y_m_d,                                                                                                                                                          1992-10-15, Thursday                                                                                                                                            1958-11-09, Sunday ```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting :( The Comments section doesn't seem to allow me to format code to clarify subsequent errors.

Comment: I think it is reading the column_name. I tried to remove the column_name and pipe that  result into the while-loop you suggested. Here is my code that gives me the above error. What should I correct?

Comment: ```  #!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                    grep -v 'y_m_d'| while read filename;                                                                                                              do                                                                                                                                                                  echo $filename, $(date -d "$filename" +%A)                                                                                      
done< testdates.csv

Comment: @sandra16 you should use [the `date` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825150/7552)